# Proper way to close files and propagate exception in the same time

Tags: java, file-io, syntax, exception

I want to safely close resources and than propagate an exception. So far I came up with two solutions.

**Solution 1**

```
FileObject sourceDir = null;
FileObject targetDir = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    // R/W operation with files
} finally {
    // close sourceDir, targetDir, br, bw
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
FileObject sourceDir = null;
FileObject targetDir = null;
BufferedWriter bw = null;
BufferedReader br = null;

try {
    // R/W operation with files
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    // close sourceDir, targetDir, br, bw
}
```

I don't like `throw e` in the second solution but `try-finally` seems a little bit unusual to me so I'm not sure which one of these I should use. Or is there any better way how to do it?

Comment: Your solution 2 is identical to Solution 1. It will only differ if you put more code in the `catch`-block (e.g., logging the exception).

Comment: I know but throwing the exception again is unnecessary piece of code. In this case I don't want to log here... I wanted to know if try-finally is ok.

Comment: Yes it is absolutely ok. Just thought you might think that the two code snippets behave differently.

Comment: @PhilippWendler No, my question is about the syntax but I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is exacly right. `try ... finally` is usually used for that.

You might even put a `return` into your try block and Java will process your `finally` and return then.

Answer (score 2):

Second solution may be useful if you want to log the exception and/or wrap it in a runtime exception and throw it.